# Reading numbers as text format with PHPExcel

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I have an array that can store numbers in such as 01, 01A, 01B, 02, 2, and When I get this value using PHPExcel, it's being removed the '0's in case of 01, 02, for example. To solve this problem, I tried to format the row where these values will be stored in excel and set it as text type, just like in the following code:

```
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('BlocksList');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($blockNames, null, 'A2');
    $latestBLColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
    $column = 'A';
    $row = 1;
    for ($column = 'A'; $column != $latestBLColumn; $column++) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($blockNames, null, 'A1');
```

So, by doing this, I get the array with numbers like 01, 01A, 02, 02B... and I store it in the Row A2. I get the highest Column to use this value in the condition For. In this condition, I set for the Row 1 in the range A until the highest column, to be formated as text.

My template is generated, and all the numbers are in text format, but the problem is that I think when I use the "`fromArray()`" method, it transforms the numbers of the array before I can get it right in excel.
Do you have any idea of how can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Formatting using a number format affects the way a number is **displayed**, not the way it is **stored**.

You'll have to **store** the numbers explicitly as strings, so you can't use fromArray().
Use setCellValueExplicit() or setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow() instead, passing a $pDataType argument of PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING.

**EDIT**

Note that you can also set styles for a range of cells, so there's no need to add the overhead of the for loop:

```
$range = 'A'.$row.':'.$latestBLColumn.$row;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($range)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
```

**EDIT #2** Using a cell binder

Create a customised cell value binder:

```
class PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder extends PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder
    implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder 
{ 
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null) 
    { 
        // sanitize UTF-8 strings 
        if (is_string($value)) { 
            $value = PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8($value); 
        } 

        // Implement your own override logic 
        if (is_string($value) && $value[0] == '0') { 
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING); 
            return true; 
        } 

        // Not bound yet? Use default value parent... 
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value); 
    } 
}
```

To avoid any problems with the autoloader, create this in the /Classes/PHPExcel/Cell directory. Otherwise, give the class your own non-PHPExcel name, and ensure that it's loaded independently.

Then, before using your fromArray() call, tell PHPExcel to use your value binder instead of the default binder:

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder() );
```

Comment: so if I have an array with 1000 values, I'll have to set each of its elements as string?

Comment: Sorry, but yes - fromArray() is a shortcut, but limited in its flexibility so it "guesses" datatypes (the cell default value binder handles this)... the alternative is to set a custom value binder that would always treat a string as a string, even if that string value is number; then you could use fromArray().

Comment: Do you know how could I set this custom value binder? This idea sounds good to me

Comment: /Tests/29advancedvaluebinder.php shows how to set a value binder. You'd need to write your own value binder, but could use either the existing default or advanced value binders as the basis for this

Comment: It's probably easiest to use the default value binder as the basis, and modify the preg_match test that tests for numeric to exclude values with a leading zero followed by a digit, or add an additional if test just before that which identifies the strings with a leading zero and returns PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING

Comment: Do you mean in this function dataTypeForValue($pValue)?

Comment: That's the one - that's the code that looks at the value you're setting for the cell, and that determines whether it's a number, string, rich text (inline), boolean, etc. The bindValue() function is the one that actually sets the cell value: the equivalent function in the advanced value binder sets (for example) a boolean type if the value being set for the cells is a string containing 'TRUE'; and also sets styles for certain cells automatically

Comment: thanks so much for this! it is kinda inperformant, though. is there anything you can to about that?

Comment: I can add it to the very long list of tasks awaiting my attention, but that's the best I can do at this point in time; but if you create a custom binder it's going to be as performant as you make it. You have the option of manually setting datatypes explicitly anyway, bypassing any binders

Comment: @user2508485 - If you want to ask a question, then ask  question - DO NOT EDIT AN EXISTING ANSWER TO ANOTHER QUESTION

Comment: it not working, Cell value =7 , format display is 7.0. After setFormatCode, result =7

Answer (score 9):

In case you need to **convert the whole sheet numbers to text**, you can use `calculateWorksheetDimension()` to get the sheet's dimensions (example: '*A1:B200*' or '*A1:C150*') and then use it in `getStyle()`, like so:

```php
// Get sheet dimension
$sheet_dimension = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension();

// Apply text format to numbers
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($sheet_dimension)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

**Note:** This example uses [*PhpSpreadsheet*](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) since it is the next version of *PHPExcel*.

Answer (score 8):

I know this was all posted a while ago, but wanted to share something that worked for me, so you can still use `->fromArray` and not have to iterate over the whole spreadsheet.

If you wrap your values in `="VALUE"` it will come through as text, and not convert it, and it will not have quotes around it in your spreadsheet

Answer (score 5):

```
$objPHPExcel
   ->getActiveSheet()
   ->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)
   ->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Comment: You should generally add some explanation or info to your answer, not just a short snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```php
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("A1","yourvalue",PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

please see here setCellValueExplicit function : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

Comment: Hi please explain the reasoning that led you to this code, code only answer will be flagged as low effort.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can format value to text with add charater before or after value. Example add after value charater ";"

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row,$user->msisdn.';' );
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Very unprofessional towards your clients in case they need Excel exports. It works but it's very dirty. Better option is converting your integers to strings with either strval($var) or (string) $var.