# PHPExcel write .xls out of an array, set cell data type to STRING/TEXT

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I want to write a .xls. My data is stored in an array like this:

```
   Array
   (
        [1] => Array
        (
               [0] => CAGL0B04213g
               [1] => Strain CBS138 chromosome B complete sequence
               [2] => 11.02.03.04
               [3] => transcriptional control
               [4] => Transcription
               [5] => 0.15831099018927
               [6] => 1
               [7] => 0.31746031746032
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
               [0] => CAGL0B04213g
               [1] => Strain CBS138 chromosome B complete sequence
               [2] => 32.01.01
               [3] => oxidative stress response
               [4] => Cell rescue, defense and virulence
               [5] => 0.09289860600029
               [6] => 1
               [7] => 1.2048192771084
        )
   )
```

I used the method `fromArray()` and it works fine but when I open the .xls with, for example LibreOffice, entries like `32.01.01` were shown as `'32.01.01` or entries like `40.01` were shown as `42,01`. I tried this ([Reading numbers as text format with PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel)) approach 
but I can't see any change. How can I write all values as STRING/TEXT and prevent that LibreOffice or Excel display them with data-format or number?

Thank you!

Comment: Quoting from accepted answer of the question you linked: `You'll have to store the numbers explicitly as strings, so you can't use fromArray(). Use setCellValueExplicit() or setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow() instead, passing a $pDataType argument of PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading numbers as text format with PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel)

Comment: okay, thank you. Now I just managed it!

Answer (score 0):

Since it applies here to, here is the important part of the accepted answer of another almost [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel):

> You'll have to store the numbers explicitly as strings, *so you can't
>   use fromArray()*. Use **setCellValueExplicit()** or
>   **setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow()** instead, passing a $pDataType
>   argument of PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING.