# phpexcel reads long numbers as boolean

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I'm using Symfony2.3.4, PHP5.6.3 and PHPExcel 1.8.0.

When I tried to read an excel file it works OK for almost all cells.

If the cell contains a very large number, when I read it and show the value in an html view it outputs **false**.

I tried to use a custom value binder like Mark Baker instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel/29689684#29689684) but I couldn't make it work, it just comes as a boolean right from the beginning.

IMPORTANT:

The excels I'm trying to load in the html are downloaded(generated) from another site and I noticed when you try to open them with Microsoft Excel, it first prompts you with a warning window telling the user that the FILE EXTENSION AND THE FILE FORMAT DO NOT MATCH, although if you choose to open it anyway, it opens fine.

I think that's what's causing the problem, I'm almost sure(I can't contact the guys who implemented the other site's download function) they did something like this:

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $ext == 'xlsx' ?
 'Excel5' : 'Excel2007');
```

when they should have done something like this:

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $ext == 'xls' ?
 'Excel5' : 'Excel2007');
```

making the EXTENSION and the FORMAT match, as instructed in the PHPExcel's docs.

If you need any specific clarification please ask.

My code to load the file into the html:

```
public function uploadAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->getForm();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){

    $form->submit($request);

    $file = $form['file'];
    $file->getData()->move(
                'uploads', $form['file']->getData()->getClientOriginalName());

    $ext = pathinfo($file->getData()->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $name = pathinfo($file->getData()->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_BASENAME);

    //$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('xlsx' == $ext ? 'Excel2007' : 'Excel5');
    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('uploads/' . $name);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('uploads/' . $name);
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $rowIter = $activeSheet->getRowIterator();
    foreach ($rowIter as $key => $row) {
        $columns = array();
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell)
            $columns[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    }
}
}
```

**NOTE:** I really don't know the difference between:

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('xlsx' == $ext ? 'Excel2007' : 'Excel5');
```

and

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('uploads/' . $name);
```

I DO know I can't use the first because of the problem I described above about the files being ill-generated and so. If I try to use it, the browser goes:

```
The filename uploads/<name>.xls is not recognised as an OLE file.
```

Can anyone point me to a workaround, because it's now me on the hook and I'm supposed to make it work somehow. Maybe there's nothing wrong with the files and it's me doing something wrong. Please help, this is causing me problems with dates too but one step at a time.

**EDIT:**

This is but the **read** function in **OLERead.php**.

I was browsing it and var_dump-ing all I could get my hands on.

As you can see there are two var_dumps in the code below, those output:

```
string '<div>    
    ' (length=8)

string '��ࡱ�' (length=8)
```

Which doesn't happen when I try it with a regular **.xls** file created manually:

```
string '��ࡱ�' (length=8)

string '��ࡱ�' (length=8)
```

I guessed you could use this better than me if it helps at all. Thanks again.

```
public function read($sFileName) {
        // Check if file exists and is readable
        if (!is_readable($sFileName)) {
            throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception("Could not open " . $sFileName . " for reading! File does not exist, or it is not readable.");
        }

        // Get the file identifier
        // Don't bother reading the whole file until we know it's a valid OLE file


        $this->data = file_get_contents($sFileName, FALSE, NULL, 0, 8);

         ////VAR_DUMPSSSSSSSSSSSS
         var_dump($this->data);
         var_dump(self::IDENTIFIER_OLE);
         die();
        // Check OLE identifier
        if ($this->data != self::IDENTIFIER_OLE) {
            throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception('The filename ' . $sFileName . ' is not recognised as an OLE file');
        }

        // Get the file data
        $this->data = file_get_contents($sFileName);

        // Total number of sectors used for the SAT
        $this->numBigBlockDepotBlocks = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, self::NUM_BIG_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCKS_POS);

        // SecID of the first sector of the directory stream
        $this->rootStartBlock = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, self::ROOT_START_BLOCK_POS);

        // SecID of the first sector of the SSAT (or -2 if not extant)
        $this->sbdStartBlock = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, self::SMALL_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCK_POS);

        // SecID of the first sector of the MSAT (or -2 if no additional sectors are used)
        $this->extensionBlock = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, self::EXTENSION_BLOCK_POS);

        // Total number of sectors used by MSAT
        $this->numExtensionBlocks = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, self::NUM_EXTENSION_BLOCK_POS);

        $bigBlockDepotBlocks = array();
        $pos = self::BIG_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCKS_POS;

        $bbdBlocks = $this->numBigBlockDepotBlocks;

        if ($this->numExtensionBlocks != 0) {
            $bbdBlocks = (self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE - self::BIG_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCKS_POS) / 4;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $bbdBlocks; ++$i) {
            $bigBlockDepotBlocks[$i] = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, $pos);
            $pos += 4;
        }

        for ($j = 0; $j < $this->numExtensionBlocks; ++$j) {
            $pos = ($this->extensionBlock + 1) * self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE;
            $blocksToRead = min($this->numBigBlockDepotBlocks - $bbdBlocks, self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE / 4 - 1);

            for ($i = $bbdBlocks; $i < $bbdBlocks + $blocksToRead; ++$i) {
                $bigBlockDepotBlocks[$i] = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, $pos);
                $pos += 4;
            }

            $bbdBlocks += $blocksToRead;
            if ($bbdBlocks < $this->numBigBlockDepotBlocks) {
                $this->extensionBlock = self::_GetInt4d($this->data, $pos);
            }
        }

        $pos = 0;
        $this->bigBlockChain = '';
        $bbs = self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE / 4;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numBigBlockDepotBlocks; ++$i) {
            $pos = ($bigBlockDepotBlocks[$i] + 1) * self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE;

            $this->bigBlockChain .= substr($this->data, $pos, 4 * $bbs);
            $pos += 4 * $bbs;
        }

        $pos = 0;
        $sbdBlock = $this->sbdStartBlock;
        $this->smallBlockChain = '';
        while ($sbdBlock != -2) {
            $pos = ($sbdBlock + 1) * self::BIG_BLOCK_SIZE;

            $this->smallBlockChain .= substr($this->data, $pos, 4 * $bbs);
            $pos += 4 * $bbs;

            $sbdBlock = self::_GetInt4d($this->bigBlockChain, $sbdBlock * 4);
        }

        // read the directory stream
        $block = $this->rootStartBlock;
        $this->entry = $this->_readData($block);

        $this->_readPropertySets();
    }
```

Comment: What does a call to `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify()` as the actual filetype?

Comment: @MarkBaker: I var_dumped `\PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('uploads/' . $name)` and it outputs **'HTML'**

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('xlsx' == $ext ? 'Excel2007' : 'Excel5');
```

and

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('uploads/' . $name);
```

The first is ***trusting*** that the extension is correct for the actual format of the file, that a file with an extension of `.xlsx` really is an `OfficeOpenXML-format` file or an extension of `.xls` really is a `BIFF-format` file, and then telling PHPExcel to use the appropriate reader.

This isn't normally a problem unless it isn't (for example) just HTML markup in a file with an `.xls` or `.xlsx` extension.... then you're selecting the wrong Reader for the actual format of the file; and this is what MS Excel itself is telling you with its message that "FILE EXTENSION AND THE FILE FORMAT DO NOT MATCH"

The second is using PHPExcel's `identify()` method to work out what format the file ***really is*** (irrespective of what it claims to be based on a false extension), and then selecting the appropriate Reader for that format.

**EDIT**

Unsure exactly how large your large numbers are, but I'll take a look at the HTML Reader and see if I can identify why it should be giving a boolean `false` instead of an actual numeric value

Comment: thank you for your interest. if it helps: the numbers are 16-digit long although I guess you'd want to find a solution for larger numbers since they're suppose to be string.
When I open them with MS Excel and I stand on a cell it displays **General** as the format.

Comment: sorry to keep bothering but, have you had the chance to look into the problem, i've tried so many readers:

(**Excel5** throws **The filename uploads/<name>.xls is not recognised as an OLE file **, **Excel2007** throws **Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in C:\...\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php line 327**)

the only one that reads the file is **HTML** and it malfunctions as I said in the question, if you have anything, even if you realize there is no solution since the files were ill-generated, let me know to report to the gallows(the boss)

Comment: I trust you are busier than me so when you can please take a look at what I found in my **EDIT**, thanks.