# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet Cannot set default format for a column or whole spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am stuck trying to set the default formatting of a particular column or whole spreadsheet. I'm using `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet` package for creating an Excel spreadsheet. Is there any way to set format of whole sheet or whole column at once?

Below is my code snippet how I have used the library:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
// Create new Spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
// Set document properties
$spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Someone')
    ->setLastModifiedBy('Someone Else')
    ->setTitle('XLSX Test Document')
    ->setSubject('Office 2007 XLSX Test Document')
    ->setDescription('PhpOffice')
    ->setKeywords('PhpOffice')
    ->setCategory('PhpOffice');

$header = [
              "Order No",
              "ID",
              "Salutaion",
              "First Name",
              "Last Name",
              "Address"
          ];
$rows = [
            [
                "SDKJFBHIDUF",
                "23123156478978945",
                "Mr.",
                "John",
                "Doe",
                "101, Lorem Ipsum"
            ]
        ];

 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
 $sheet->setTitle('Orders');
 $sheet->fromArray($header, null, 'A1');
 $sheet->fromArray($rows, null, 'A2');
 $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="samplemultitab-invoice-' . time() . '.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
 // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
 header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
 header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
 header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
 header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
 $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
 $writer->save('php://output');
 exit;
```

For now I'm modifying `/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php` file `fromArray` method to as below

```
$this->getCell($currentColumn . $startRow)->setValue($cellValue);
```

to

```
$this->getCell($currentColumn . $startRow)->setValueExplicit($cellValue,\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

But I need a valid approach to fix this generic option setting.

Comment: I would advice to add more code to the code you are displaying.
Its hard to help you without some context of the code.

Comment: Hello @acarlstein, I've just updated the question, please check now

Comment: @SandeepJPatel How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with large ID strings (1234567890123456789, for instance) being automatically converted to numbers and displayed as 1.23456789012346E+018 in my spreadsheet.

When using `getStyle($columnIndex)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode()` you have to use the values from PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat class and although there is a "FORMAT_TEXT" value, it seems to be too late because the cell values are considered as  numbers (Cell\DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC) already and not as pure strings.

From my own experience I assumed that the only (and cumbersome) solution was to iterate over the cells of the given column to use the `setValueExplicit()` method.

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
// Fill the sheet with values using fromArray() method
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataToFillTheSheet, NULL, 'A1');
// Get the highest row index
$highestRow = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
for($i = 1; $i <= $highestRow; $i++) {
  $cell = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, $i);
  $cell->setValueExplicit($cell->getValue(), \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
}
```

I'd be interested to know if anyone knows a better solution, though.

Comment: This is more about how the values are stored in the Excel file, than the cell formatting asked about in the question. Formatting is strictly cosmetic. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12457610/1255289) and its answers for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet` object, this should do it for the whole sheet:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;

$ss->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        DataType::TYPE_STRING
    );
```

For a column:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;

$ss->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle("A")
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Comment: Hi @miken32, I tried your solution but its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem with single values, the position was important.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
    );
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to set the explicit value, with TYPE_STRING, THEN set the style to FORMAT_TEXT.

```
$sheet->getCell('A1')->setValueExplicit('0000001', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Comment: This solution was already given [as an answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64605887/1255289)

Answer (score -1):

you can set format code to the active sheet like this

```
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("file_path");
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:C20")
                    ->getNumberFormat()
                    ->setFormatCode('General');
```