# PHPSpreadsheet load CSV setting default data format

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I am loading a CSV file via PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv.  My 1st column contains a large number (15191100011) that I want loaded as the data format TEXT and not GENERAL.  Because if it loaded as general it displays as 1.52E+10.

If you manually import via Excel | File | Import the last question asked is the column data format which defaults to General, but I select Text for the first column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading numbers as text format with PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457610/reading-numbers-as-text-format-with-phpexcel)